# How to exclude subdirectories from using a package with CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, directory, structure, sfml

I am currently working on a rogue like game just to get the hang of game development. I recently decided to clean up my directory structure and divide this into a directory with the game logic (Entities, Camera, Random, ...) and one for the game representation that uses SFML utilities. So my directory structure looks something like this: (please don't make fun of me it is my first time using subdirectories in CMake)

```
myProject
 /engine
  /include
   /Random.h
  /src
   /Random.cpp
  CMakeLists.txt
 /game
  /include
   /IView.h
   /PlayerView.h
  /src
   /IView.cpp
   /PlayerView.cpp
  CMakeLists.txt
CMakeLists.txt
```

I want my top `CMakeLists.txt` to create a target using the two subdirectories, but the `/engine` directory should not be able to use any SFML Utilities, so for example if I use `#include "SFML/Graphics.cpp"` in the `Random.h` file I get an CMake error. It also doesn't use any functions or classes from the `/game` directory. On the other-hand the `/game` directory needs to be able to use SFML utilities and relies on the `/engine` directory.

This is what I currently got, but it gives me an undefined symbols error.:

```
[ 72%] Linking CXX shared library libgame.dylib
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "sf::RenderStates::Default", referenced from:
      View::IView::onDraw() in IView.cpp.o
```

**Top CMakeLists.txt**

```
project(myProject VERSION 1.0)

ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(engine)
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(game)

ADD_EXECUTABLE(myProject src/main.cpp)

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(myProject PUBLIC engine)

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(myProject PUBLIC game)

INSTALL(TARGETS myProject DESTINATION ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
```

**Engine CMakeLists.txt**

```
SET(SRC

        Random.cpp
)
ADD_LIBRARY(engine SHARED ${SRC})
TARGET_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(engine PUBLIC include)
```

**Game CMakeLists.txt**

```
SET(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}../cmake/Modules/")

FIND_PACKAGE(SFML 2 COMPONENTS system window graphics audio)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${SFML_INCLUDE_DIR})

SET(SRC
        IView.cpp
        PlayerView.cpp
        )

ADD_LIBRARY(game SHARED ${SRC})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(game engine)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(game ${SFML_LIBRARIES})

TARGET_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(game PUBLIC include)
```

Comment: What you are currently doing looks reasonable.

Comment: ***but the /engine directory should not be able to use any SFML Utilities*** if you have SFML in your system include folders it would still be able to include. I am thinking of /usr/include /opt/include /usr/local/include /include ...

Comment: @Tsyvarev I added it now!

Comment: @drescherjm Yeah i have it in my /usr folder. So If I really needed to do this I should move it from /usr to /myProject right?

Comment: I would leave the headers in the system location especially if your distro put them there.

Comment: So the error is solely about your `game` library created in `game` subdirectory. How the title - "How to exclude subdirectories from using a package with CMake" - is connected with the problem? As for the error itself, have you checked the content of the variable `SFML_LIBRARIES` which you use for linking? It should be non-empty at least.

Comment: @drescherjm: The `2` in `FIND_PACKAGE(SFML 2 COMPONENTS system window graphics audio)` denotes a **version** of the package to search. Actually, except missed `REQUIRED` keyword, that call is same as in the [example](https://github.com/SFML/SFML-Game-Development-Book/blob/master/CMake/FindSFML.cmake#L53).